# Implementing Sqlalchemy beaker caching in pyramid framework

Tags: python, caching, sqlalchemy, pyramid, beaker

As per the example provided by sqlalchemy documentation to cache a sqlalchemy query we are suppose to do this

```
from caching_query import FromCache

# load Person objects.  cache the result under the namespace "all_people".
print "loading people...."
people = Session.query(Person).options(FromCache("default", "all_people")).all()
```

I have the following configuration for beaker in development.ini

```
cache.regions = day, hour, minute, second
cache.type = file
cache.data_dir = %(here)s/cache/sess/data
cache.lock_dir = %(here)s/cache/sess/lock
cache.second.expire = 1
cache.minute.expire = 60
cache.hour.expire = 3600
cache.day.expire = 86400
```

When i use the above example code in my application data is not cached in the cache folder, so i am assuming memory based caching is the default, Is it possible to switch sqlalchemy cache type to file based? or am i getting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some details, but let me try:

- the first parameter passed to `FromCache()` is a name of a Beaker cache region, it should match one of the configured regions, which is not the case here. Or perhaps you configure `default` region in the code (I'd expect `BeakerException` being thrown if region is unknown)?
- you need `pyramid_beaker` module installed and included in Pyramid's project configuration. I suggest you follow `pyramid_beaker` [manual's *Setup* section](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/#setup).
- you need some extra code in `__init__.py` of your application in order to propagate `.ini` file settings to Beaker. This is described in [*Beaker cache region support*](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/#beaker-cache-region-support) section of the manual.

And here's a working sample from my current project, configuring both Beaker-based sessions and caching (all irrelevant parts removed):

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid_beaker import set_cache_regions_from_settings
from pyramid_beaker import session_factory_from_settings

def main(global_config, **settings):
    # Configure Beaker caching/sessions    
    set_cache_regions_from_settings(settings)
    session_factory = session_factory_from_settings(settings)

    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.set_session_factory(session_factory)
    config.include('pyramid_beaker')

    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')

    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```